# Diagonal movement behaving strangely when other key is pressed

Tags: javascript

I'm following the tutorial at http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-canvas-game-the-player-ship/. I'm at the part where bullets get added to the game. Prior to this in the section about movement where I split the movement loop into two seperate loops, one for up-down and the other for right-left movement. When one of each is pressed the ship moves diagonaly.

How it was presented in the tutorial.

```
if (KEY_STATUS.left) {
            this.x -= this.speed
            if (this.x <= 0) // Keep player within the screen
                this.x = 0;
        } else if (KEY_STATUS.right) {
            this.x += this.speed
            if (this.x >= this.canvasWidth - this.width)
                this.x = this.canvasWidth - this.width;
        } else if (KEY_STATUS.up) {
            this.y -= this.speed
            if (this.y <= this.canvasHeight/4*3)
                this.y = this.canvasHeight/4*3;
        } else if (KEY_STATUS.down) {
            this.y += this.speed
            if (this.y >= this.canvasHeight - this.height)
                this.y = this.canvasHeight - this.height;
        }
        // Finish by redrawing the ship
        this.draw();
```

What I did.

```
 if (KEY_STATUS.left && this.x >= 0) {
            this.x -= this.speed
        }
        else if (KEY_STATUS.right && this.x <= this.canvasWidth - this.width) {
            this.x += this.speed
        }
        if (KEY_STATUS.down && this.y <= this.canvasHeight - this.height) {
            this.y += this.speed
        }
        else if (KEY_STATUS.up && this.y >= 0) {
            this.y -= this.speed
        }

        // Finish by redrawing the ship
        this.draw();
```

All was fine at first, the ship was moving as I wanted it to. Then I added.

```
if (KEY_STATUS.space && counter >= fireRate) {
        this.fire();
        counter = 0;
    }
```

Now the movements work fine untill I press the Space key. This is what confused me the most. While Space is pressed, only the UP+Right, diagonal movement works, while all the other default to one or the other.
 Ex: UP+Left gives Up or Left depending on which was pressed first.
 As far as I can tell the problem has nothing to do with the order of the comands in the loops. Some sources suggest that it might be a problem with my keyboard.BTW, I've ran across this problem with a similar project(c++,sfml). So am I messing up something in my code or should I get a new keyboard?
PS: I copied almost all of the code from the tutorial.Still has the same problem.

Comment: Many keyboards can handle only some simultaneous key presses. I believe shift, ctrl, alt are more likely to work with other keys than space, but I am not certain. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)